# How to return mongodb query result with hapi js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, hapi.js

I've been trying to build APIs with Hapi, started with something simple as returning all users from database:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/users',
    handler: (request, h) => {
        var users;
        collection.find({}).toArray((err, users) => {      
            console.log(res)
            // I want to return the list of users here
            // return users // this one does not work
            // return h.response(users) // does not work either
        });

        return "" // or here
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are there any errors? Are you using the MongoDB node driver? Is the db connection successful and `collection` variable declared correctly (pointing to a valid collection)?

Comment: There's no error, the `Console.log` did show the expected result (an array of users) so I suppose the connection and query are good. Yes, I'm using MongoDB node drive
`const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cursor.toArray() returns a promise instead of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174078/cursor-toarray-returns-a-promise-instead-of-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do :

```
server.route({
 method: 'GET',
 path: '/',
 handler: (request, h) => {        
   return collection.find({}).toArray()
  //return collection.findOne({}) // Or like this, to just return one result
 }
});
```

Comment: indeed, this works like a charm and it's simpler than I thought.